# Running time for a shortestP alg in unweighted undirected graph in python3

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance

For this kind of problem I thought it would have been better make some BFS-like implementation. I don't know why, after some running time testing, it came out a plot that resembles an exponential function.

So I began to think of my code's correctness: is it really efficient? Can you help me to make a running time analysis for a good algorithm?

I've plotted the log in base 1.5 for the x-axis (since in the code I use a list of the first 30 powers of 1.5 as number of vertices input in a random graph generetor). Still looks exponential...

```
def bfs_short(graph, source, target):
    visited = set()
    queue = collections.deque([source])

    d={}
    d[source]=0

    while queue:
        u = queue.pop()
        if u==target:
            return d[target]
        if u not in visited:
            visited.add(u)
            for w in graph[u]:
                if w not in visited:
                    queue.appendleft(w)
                    d[w]=d[u]+1
```

The thing is... I didn't posted also the benching input trials which also may cause problems but first of all I want to be sure that the code works fine... solving the problems related to testing is my final purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A problem in your code is that your queue does not take in account the distance to the origin in order to prioritize the next vertex it will pop.
Also, `collections.deque` is not a priority queue, and thus will not give you the closest unvisited vertex seen so far when you pop an element from it.
This should do it, using `heapq`, a built-in heap implementation:

```
import heapq

def bfs_short(graph, source, target):
    visited = set()
    queue = [(0, source)]
    heapq.heapify(queue)
    while not queue:
        dist, vertex = heapq.heappop(queue)
        if vertex == target:
            return dist
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            for neighbor in graph[vertex]:
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    heapq.heappush(queue, (dist + 1, neighbor))
```

In this version, pairs are pushed in the queue. To evaluate and compare tuples, Python tries to compare their first element, then the second in case of equality, and on and on.
So by pushing `dist(vertex, origin)` as first member of the tuple, the smallest couple `(dist, vertex)` in the heap will also be the closest to the origin vertex.